# HTTP Post request returning 404 when called from php script, but works when called from a node.js script. Endpoint is valid

Tags: php, node.js, http-status-code-404

In the code samples below, I replaced the API endpoint with a placeholder endpoint, but they are the exact same between the php and node.js scripts. Also note that the endpoint being hit is hosted on an Azure app service that's behind an Azure front door. I do see the 404 errors in the app service logs though.

Here's the php script:

```
$apiKey = "someAPIKey";
$accountId = "someAccountId";
$txRequest = createTransaction(); // This is JSON

$baseUri = "https://someapiendpoint.com/graphql";
$headers = [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "X-API-KEY: $apiKey",
    "Account: $accountId",
];

echo $txRequest;

$ch = curl_init($baseUri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $txRequest);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response === FALSE) {
    echo "cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n";
}

echo $response;
```

Response from php function:

```
* Connected to someapiendpoint.com (xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=someapiendpoint.com
*  start date: Jun 11 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 11 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "someapiendpoint.com" matched cert's "someapiendpoint.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert, Inc.; CN=GeoTrust Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify result: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* h2h3 [:method: POST]
* h2h3 [:path: /graphql]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: someapiendpoint.com]
* h2h3 [accept: application/json]
* h2h3 [x-api-key: someAPIKey]
* h2h3 [account: someAccountId]
* h2h3 [content-length: 1187]
* h2h3 [content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x264ace0f260)
> POST /graphql HTTP/2
Host: someapiendpoint.com
accept: application/json
x-api-key: someAPIKey
account: someAccountId
content-length: 1187
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 404 
< date: Thu, 05 Oct 2023 22:43:53 GMT
< content-length: 0
< x-robots-tag: noindex,nofollow
< x-correlation-id: 000000000000000000000000
< x-azure-ref: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
< x-cache: CONFIG_NOCACHE
<
* Connection #0 to host someapiendpoint.com left intact
```

Here's the node.js script:

```
const response = await axios.post(
    'https://someapiendpoint.com/graphql',
    txRequest, // This is JSON
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'X-API-KEY':
          'someAPIKey',
        Account: 'someAccountId',
      },
    }
  );
console.log(response.data);
```

The node.js script responds with a 200 response with the expected response body.

Comment: Could it be balking on the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? It expects either an array or a urlencoded string.

Comment: I tried passing an empty string instead of the $txRequest variable, but I'm still getting a 404 error.

Comment: Everything looks ok from the code. Only thing I can think of is there are cookies expected. I see Azure, so wouldn't doubt it.  The js code shown isn't handling that, unless you're setting withCredentials as an axios default.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what's going on. I'm not setting any defaults for axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I finally found the issue...

I had to add the header "Content-Type" and set it to "application/json". Once that header was added, then I got a 200 response and it all worked.

Code for header added:

```
$headers = [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json", // This is what I added
    "X-API-KEY: $apiKey",
    "Account: $accountId",
];
```